# Solving a second order linear differential inequation with some given conditions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $f$ be a twice differentiable function on the open interval $(-1,1)$ such that $f(0)=1$. Suppose $f$ also satisfies $f(x)≥0$, $f'(x)≤0$ and $f''(x)≤f(x)$, for all $x≥0$. Show that $f'(0)≥-\sqrt2$.

When I first saw this question, I tried to multiply the differential inequation

> $f''(x)-f(x)≤0$

by some function $g(x)$ to convert it into a form something like $(f(x).g(x))''≤0$ and then use properties of decreasing functions (which is what I would have done if it was a first order differential inequation, where I would choose $g(x)$ to be the integrating factor...). I tried functions like $g(x)=e^x$, $g(x)=e^{-x}$, $g(x)=sin(x)$, $g(x)=cos(x)$ etc., but in vain. Then I was stuck and out of ideas.

I have seen solutions to similar problems which use [Taylor's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem), but that is beyond the scope of my syllabus, as I am currently a high school student and this question is from an undergraduate entrance exam.

Can someone please help in solving this problem using some elementary techniques?

Comment: This video (https://youtu.be/6qFJbQFZg_4) contains the solution using Taylor's theorem (question 4).

Comment: Yes it does, thank you so much. I searched a lot on stack exchange but couldn't find this question. Probably didn't search well enough...